# is there a javascript structure that allows to map multiple keys (non nested) to 1 single value

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
["a", "b"] -> 1
["c", "d", "e"] -> 2
```

I want to be able to give "d" as key and get 2.

Comment: What about a plain map?

Comment: You could create a proxy with a custom handler, or a class, but why not just set each property individually?

Comment: You can assign an object to many variables and it will remain just _one_ object. Changing properties in one variable can be seen to have changed in all other variables too. But primitives will be assigned individually and their values will not be linked.

Comment: Those "values" (`1`, `2` in your example) are supposed to be unique across the structure?  Just like it was internally "inverted map" with number keys and array values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work with your example, but I am not sure it covers your real life case :D

```js
const arrays = [['a','b'],['c','d','e']]
const struct = arrays.reduce((acc, array, index) => {
  array.forEach(v => acc[v] = index + 1)
  return acc
}, {})
console.log(struct)
console.log(struct.d)
```

output

```
{a: 1, b: 1, c: 2, d: 2, e: 2}
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an object like this:

```js
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 2,
  "d": 2,
  "e": 2,
}
```

but this has the problem of if you wanted to change all `1`s to `3`, you'd have to change it in each place.

You can do this:

```js
const data = [1, 2];
const map = {
  "a": data[0],
  "b": data[0],
  "c": data[1],
  "d": data[1],
  "e": data[1],
}
```

so that you only have to set the result in one place.

---

you can also do stuff with `Set`s or nested arrays, but that prevents the lookup from being O(1) and changes it to O(n) or O(n*m) based on implementation.

Comment: of course you'd need setters for each, and mutating `data` doesn't update `map`

Comment: @pilchard what do you mean? if you wanted to modify the map at runtime, the builtin object can do that automatically Edit: this can be updated if OP will be changing the map at runtime

Comment: I mean if the OP expects grouped properties to stay synced if setting new values you'll need a mechanism for that. But sure as a one time mapping this is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if exactly what you are looking for but you can do it with built-in object and array methods.

```js
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(["c", "d", "e"]).map((a) => {
    a.reverse();
    a[1] = Number(a[1]);
    return a;
  })
);
```

This will output:

```js
 { c: 0, d: 1, e: 2 }
```

But I see you want to start from 1 and not 0, in that case you could map bit more:

```js
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(["c", "d", "e"]).map((a) => {
    a.reverse();
    a[1] = Number(a[1]) + 1;
    return a;
  })
);
```

Then you get

```js
{ c: 1, d: 2, e: 3 }
```